# Compare two pandas dataframes and show diferences

Tags: python, pandas

imagine two datasets

I want to compare DF1 against DF2 and show only the records that are missing or different in DF2

I.e

df1

```
+----+-------+-----+
| id | Name  | Age |
+----+-------+-----+
| 1  | Lewis | 65  |
+----+-------+-----+
| 2  | Fred  | 35  |
+----+-------+-----+
| 3  | Amy   | 16  |
+----+-------+-----+
```

df2

```
+----+-------+-----+
| id | Name  | Age |
+----+-------+-----+
| 1  | Lewis | 65  |
+----+-------+-----+
| 2  | Fred  | 36  |
+----+-------+-----+
```

Output

```
+-----+-------+-----+
| Id  | Name  | Age |
+-----+-------+-----+
| 2   | Fred  | 36  |
+-----+-------+-----+
| 3   | Amy   | 16  |
+-----+-------+-----+
```

I know I could concat both and drop duplicates but it will only show me the missing items from both?

Any suggestions how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use merge with an indicator

```
df = df1.merge(df2, how='outer', on=['Id','Name','Age'], indicator=True)
```

You can access all the missing values or different values by filtering on indicator

Comment: Very nice use of merge ;) +1 Would be nice to provide a full answer though, like adding `.query('_merge != "both"').drop('_merge', axis=1)`